# mPDF, dynamic table to be 100% height

Tags: php, css, mpdf

I am generating PDFs using the mPDF library, currently the user can create a table in a WYSIWIG editor, that HTML gets stored in a database and I pull it back within mPDF as seen below:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/1z5mbvb.jpg

I would like to make the table expand to fill the entire page, is this possible?

Comment: Please did you finally find the way to fix this? I need the same behaviour for my app